# Dns.GetHostAddresses throws socket exception on Dns.GetHostName even though Dns.GetHostName returns correct user

Tags: c#, sockets, dns, localhost, hostname

MSDN definitions for `Dns.GetHostAddresses` and `Dns.GetHostName` are as follows:

`Dns.GetHostName` - Gets the host name of the local computer.

`Dns.GetHostAddresses` - Returns the Internet Protocol (IP) addresses for the specified host.

When I run `Dns.GetHostName()` the result is the expected host. However, when I run `Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName())`, I get a socket exception which I believe indicates the lookup of the ip address for the host name has failed.

Shouldn't the local machines host name have an IP assigned to it? Where is this figured and how can I assign my local host name to the default `127.0.0.1` address? Where might I look for any misconfigured network settings?

Thank you very much for your time. Please let me know if I am being unclear or if you need anything else from me.

Comment: Since GetHostAddresses uses a DNS server (which probably has no clue about your hostname), the error is expected. You could add your machine´s name to the _hosts_ file to avoid it.